# New build shuts down randomly - insufficient power?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, crash, shutdown, reboot

I have an ongoing problem with my new build shutting down randomly. It is very sporadic: it can be 5 times a day, or once in 5 days.

My temperatures are fine, I have tested the wall sockets and have the latest (Asus BIOS). After shutting down, the reboot/shutdown cycle loops until I manually power off. On reboot, there is no anti-surge warning.

Recently, I unplugged 2 120mm fans, 2 sticks of RAM and an SSD. It has not happened since. I am wondering if my power supply is insufficient (although it is an AX860i from Corsair). Is that possible, particularly if the Titan is drawing a lot of power?!

```
Spec: 
Intel i7 5820
EVGA Titan X Hybrid
8 x 8GB DDR4 RAM (Corsair Vengeance)
6 x 120mm fans 
Noctua D15 cooler
4 x Samsung EVO SSDs
Corsair AX860i PSU
Sabretooth X99 mobo
```

---

By 'shutting down' I just mean the power suddenly cuts off, as if I had turned off the wall socket, there is no normal shutdown procedure.

I am using Ubuntu, where is the events log please? Thanks.

---

The incident happened again today. Instead of turning it off during the reboot cycle, I left it to resolve. I then got the error message from Asus saying that it was due to the **Asus anti-surge protection** because power surges had been detected.

I am extremely reluctant to turn the anti-surge protection off, in case my components are damaged by a genuine power surge. Is there any alternative?

---

**Thanks for all the responses. I replaced my PSU with a EVGA SuperNOVA 1200 P2 and have had no problems since. So, either the Corsair 860W PSU was insufficient or it was faulty.**

Comment: Sounds like a good theory from the test. Also a "weak" power supply with aged caps could become more "dirty" power as the load was higher. What do you mean by "shutting down"? because that infers that the system shut down, and the (windows) system is capable of automatic restarts. Does it just slam power off or do any sort of shut-down routine?  Are there ever any events created at that time?

Comment: I would turn off the anti-surge anyway for testing, it is very pickey, and you should test without it a bit.  I dont do ubuntu , but people who follow it may follow based on a TAG for it, which you could add, and to remove the reboot one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

Change your PSU to more than 1000 watts. (1200w/1500w)

**Explanation:**

Even if you didn't mention your PSU Watts, I'm sure your problem is a PSU shortage watt. As you have:

- Intel i7 (around 140w)
- 8x8GBRAM (around 35w)
- EVGA Titan X Hybrid (requires at least 600 Watt)
- D15 cooler system (requires at least 140w)
- 6x additional 120mm fans(around 15w)
- 4x SSDs (around 16w)

Doing the math with adding an additional 250 watts to the results as a safety room for your computer, you would end up needing more than 1000 Watts for the current built.

When you pick the PSU, you have to see how much watts you need from the hardware requirements, and then add between 100 to 300 additional watts (depends on your usage), which will cover any shortage that you may experience in the future from usage or adding new components or overclock. Plus, some external connected devices are also counted in. Any device you connected to the computer that DOES NOT have a dedicated power supplier will use PSU power, which means more watts will be used.

So, again, your computer needs more watts to be consumed, but your PSU couldn't offer them. That's why when you unplugged 2 120mm fans, 2 sticks of RAM and an SSD, the computer went back to normal because you free some watts from being consumed.

Comment: The CPU is rated at 140W not 35W and the GPU is rated at 250W not 600W.

Comment: @James thanks for correction, and the GPU required at least 600 watt PSU from the manufacture itself take a look here : http://www.evga.com/Products/Specs/GPU.aspx?pn=33AFF248-1A09-48B0-85D6-6F7B4CE99DB2.

Comment: They are saying that they recommend a 600W or greater PSU for the whole system, see here: https://www.overclockers.co.uk/evga-geforce-titan-x-hybrid-12288mb-gddr5-pci-express-graphics-card-12g-p4-1999-kr-gx-287-ea.html?gclid=CN-p9KSumswCFfUV0wodyU8ClA.

Comment: @James I've seen the world test article, and I agree with you, but I used the 600w as start number to add other watts on it, so it won't be less than 600w. Thus, we won't have any shortage in the future. If I said 250w and do the rest of the math I will end up with less than 900w which is less than it requires to operate his system. (probably his PSU is around that number as well). while his system needs more than 1000w to work. I might be wrong, but this is what I've experienced, and I will be happy to learn from you.

Comment: I somewhat agree, the 850 should do just fine when not overclocking at all, overclocking itself (assuming that was done on any of it by increasing the voltage) can make a huge variation. Like in a quad CPU it could doubble the watts easy even before an excess voltage like >1.4v and if your doing that using asus or gigabytes "Auto" method instead of man voltage control, it is  less controlled.   I think people underestimate the power effect of raising any voltage above "normal"  Also many times PSU geeks have shown that "which PSU" it is can vary its actual ability a lot, meaning it depends.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

Check your Power Supply current (amperes) rating, your particular PSU has software for this.

**Long Answer**

More often than not people will blame the the low wattage of a PSU for power failure, but a 2000W PSU with a low current tolerence will be useless for a Graphics card like this, which has a recommended PSU tolerance of 42 Amps.

This is a common issue, when the BitCoin craze started and people were buying GPU's left right and center, a LOT blew their PSU's / had them shut down because they only looked at the Wattage and not the internal current ratings.